# How to deal with tags in a normalized database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, tags, normalization

I am trying to normalize a database I am building. One part of it is that I have many different tests that each can have many different tags. How would you deal with this?

Would you have a table with your tags and then have a limit on the number of tags per test?

I am new to databases let alone the whole idea of normalizing so forgive me if this is a very simplistic question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this'd be dealt with using two tables. A `tags` table, with each record consisting of a `tag_id` and `tag_name` (and potentially other metadata you want to include). Tags would then be associated with their tests via another table, `test_tags`, in which `test_id` and `tag_id` would be stored.

If you want to limit the number of tags per test, you can easily run a `SELECT COUNT(tag_id) FROM test_tags WHERE test_id=#` query to figure out how many they've already added to it.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the way you would do this would be to have one table `tags`, like:

```
INT id PRIMARY KEY
VARCHAR(255) name
```

Then for each object you allow to be tagged, you need a bridge table.  So if you have another table `tests` with its own `id` column, you would have another table, `tests_tags`:

```
INT test_id PRIMARY KEY
INT tag_id PRIMARY KEY
```

You can then enumerate all tests with a tag by getting the test ids where `tag_id` is the tag id you are interested in; likewise you can enumerate all tags on a test by getting the tag ids where `test_id` is the test id you are interested in.

This is the standard way to model a many-to-many relationship.